# What does the notation 5(4) , 3(2), etc. mean exactly in Runge-Kutta pairs?

Tags: numerical-methods

The Runge Kutta methods usually are listed as pairs like 5(4), 3(2), and the like. Do these mean the maximum value of $i$ in $k_i$ in the RK methods. But yet that would be only 1 number. What is the other? And do these pairs occur only as adjacent numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are usually used for [embedded RK methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods#Embedded_methods), that are methods with two different $b$ vectors with different order. By comparing solutions obtained from different order methods one can estimate local truncation error *a posteriori* and thus estimate the best integration step to achieve required accuracy.

The order of embedded RK methods is usually written as $p(q)$ with $p$-th order method used for actual computation of $u_{n+1}$ and $q$-th order method is used for the error estimate. $p$ and $q$ may be quite different, but usually they are taken to be close.

For example, famous Dormand-Prince method is a 5(4) order method, since it uses fifth order solution for the next step and the fourth order for the error estimate.

You can find more of this in [Solving Ordinary Differential Equations I](https://profs.info.uaic.ro/~fliacob/An2/2014-2015/Resurse_MCM_2015/Hairer,%20Norsett,%20Wanner_Solving%20Ordinary%20Differential%20Equations%20I.pdf) by Hairer, Norsett and Wanner, sections II.4 and II.5.

Comment: Consequently, does Fehlberg 4(5) use a fourth-order solution for the next step, and a fifth-order solution for the error estimate, or is this just an inconsistency?

Comment: @JamesTurner exactly, in RKF4(5) the higher order method is used only for the error estimate, and the lower order is tuned to yield the least truncation error possible.

Comment: Great, thanks uranix.